# PHP- Getting yesterdays data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to get yesterdays entries in the database. Any ideas on what query I should run? Its been blowing my mind for the last hour!

mysql_query("SELECT  `id` , `fullname` , `address1` , `address2` , `citytown` , `postcode` , `telno` , `email` , `property_value` , `on_market` , `agent` , `asking_price` , `reason` , `total_secured_debt` , `price_concession` , FROM_UNIXTIME( enquiry_time ) , `form_page` FROM $table WHERE enquiry_time=??????????");

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 3):

What about using the function [`date_sub`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) ?

For instance, to get yesterday (same time than now) :

```
select date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);
```

And to get yesterday, without specifying the time :

```
select date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day));
```

So your condition could be like

```
where enquiry_time >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
    and enquiry_time < date(date_sub(now(), interval 0 day))
```

*(at least, if `enquiry_time` includes time ; if it only includes date, an = would be enough)*

Answer (score 1):

How about using [TO_DAYS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) to turn the time into a day number, and check it against yesterdays day number:

```
WHERE TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME( enquiry_time )) = (TO_DAYS(NOW())-1)
```